# regarding threads and runnables

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I am having a problem understanding the differences between some kinds of making a tread loop.

one is (a rough demonstration):

```
Thread thread=new Thread("name") {
public void run()
  {
  // do stuff
  }
}.start();
```

the second is:
 making a class that imlpements runnable,
 creating a thread :

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this,"name").start();
```

and the third (in android, i don't if it can work some how else):
 making a Handler,
 creating a Runnable,
 and having `handler.postDelayed(runnable)`, or `handler.post(runnable)`.

I don't understand what's the difference, the only thing i did notice is that making a Thread makes the run loop work a lot faster than using a handler.
could some one explain to me what's the difference between them and what should i use to what?

Comment: Re-using a thread can perform better otherwise they are all the same.  Its considered bad practice extending Thread as this can lead to all sorts of unexpected errors.

Comment: in what way do i re use a thread?, using a handler? or just making a simple Thread thread?

Comment: You can re-use a Thread with a thread pool e.g. ExecutorService or an event thread which is created for you such as the UI thread.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and the second way are exactly the same. It is just different constructions that can be more useful in different situations. Note that `Thread` implements `Runnable` and may just run himself in the new thread.

The third way is a little bit misinterpreted by you. `Handler` runs `Runnable` in the thread where the `Handler` was instantiated (unless you specify another looper). If you created your `Handler` in the UI thread it will run `Runnable` in the UI thread as well. And as a result it may work slower.

Comment: I would caveat this with saying that unless you have a really good reason, don't extend the Thread class.  Stick with implementing the Runnable interface.

Comment: Is there any good reasons of not overriding thread's run method besides esthetical separation of logical structures? Any potential problems that may be important to know?

Comment: Not necessarily a problem, but a `Runnable` could also be passed to an `ExecutorService`. Although you could also pass a `Thread` object, it would be confusing and unnecessary.

Comment: I totally agree that separate `Runnable` looks more like a good practice. I mentioned overriding `Thread` class just because it was in the question.

Comment: Thread is a heavyweight object.  Look at its code.  It has maps for thread locals, etc.  Use the simplest approach imho